# How to display a userName in Navbar in ASP.NET core Razor Page

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, navbar, identity

I am working on ASP.NET core Razor pages using Windows Authentication.

I have created a WindowsIdentity.cs class which get the Identity of a Windows Authenticated user, using HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name to get the username of the currently authenticated user.

In *index.cshtml(index.cshtml.cs) * file created an instance of the of the WindowsIdentity.cs and get the UserName, which I need to display it on the NavBar. So the username is consistent across all the pages of the website. How can I get the **UserName **in the Navbar

*Windows Identity.cs class*

```
public WindowsUserIdentity(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
 {
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
            _userName = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;

}//end of WindowsUserIdentity() 
                
public string GetUserIdentity()
{
     return _userName;

}//end of GetUserIdentity()



public IndexModel(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)        
{

     WindowsUserIdentity winUserIdentity = new WindowsUserIdentity(httpContextAccessor);
     _userName= winUserIdentity.GetUserIdentity();   
 }//end of IndexModel
`your text`
`your text`
public void OnGet()
{
     //Assign the userName to ViewData to be accessed from all the pages.
     ViewData["UserName"] = _userName;
            
}//end of OnGet()`
```

Comment: Why not use `<p class="nav navbar-text">Hello, @User.Identity?.Name!</p>` to show UserName in layout directly like the default windows identity template do?

Comment: Xinran Shen, Thank you so much for your help.  It worked the way as I expected. !!!!!

Comment: Question- With @User.Identity?.Name!, it gives me the UserID for eg. jsmith. Now I want the Name of the signed In user i,.e John Smith, How can I get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the name of user in `Layout` page directly via `public virtual ClaimsPrincipal User { get; }` property.

```
<ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
     <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index">Home</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Privacy">Privacy</a>
     </li>
</ul>
<p class="nav navbar-text">Hello, @User.Identity?.Name!</p>
```

When user log in, user name will be showed in Navbar.

[image]